# Images are not showing up in front end (Spring boot + View Engine: Thymeleaf)

Tags: spring-boot, image, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Images saved as filenames in DB is not rendering thus not shown in the front page.

```
**Model:
**
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductDto {

    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @NotEmpty
    private double costPrice;
    @NotEmpty
    private double salePrice;
    @NotEmpty
    private int currentQuantity;
    @NotEmpty
    private Category category;
    private Brand brand;
    private List<String> imageUrls;
} 

**DTO:**
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductDto {

    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @NotEmpty
    private double costPrice;
    @NotEmpty
    private double salePrice;
    @NotEmpty
    private int currentQuantity;
    @NotEmpty
    private Category category;
    private Brand brand;
    private List<String> imageUrls;
    private boolean productActivated;
    private boolean productDeleted;

}

**Controller:
**
@GetMapping("/products")
    public String products(Model model , Principal principal){
        if(principal==null){
            return "redirect:/login";
        }

        List<ProductDto> productDtoList=productService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("title", "Manage Product");
        model.addAttribute("products", productDtoList);
        model.addAttribute("size",productDtoList.size());
        return "products";
    }

**Service implementation for findAll method:
**
@Override
    public List<ProductDto> findAll() {
        List<ProductDto> productDtoList=new ArrayList<>();
        List<Product> products=productRepository.findAll();
        for(Product product:products){
            ProductDto productDto=new ProductDto();
            productDto.setId(product.getId());
            productDto.setName(product.getName());
            productDto.setDescription(product.getDescription());
            productDto.setCostPrice(product.getCostPrice());
            productDto.setSalePrice(product.getSalePrice());
            productDto.setCurrentQuantity(product.getCurrentQuantity());
            productDto.setCategory(product.getCategory());
            productDto.setBrand(product.getBrand());
            List<String> imageUrls=product.getImageUrls();
            productDto.setImageUrls((imageUrls));
            productDto.setProductActivated(product.isProductActivated());
            productDto.setProductDeleted(product.isProductDeleted());
            productDtoList.add(productDto);
        }
        return productDtoList;
    }

**Service implementation for save method:
**
 @Override
    public Product save(List<MultipartFile> imageFiles, ProductDto productDto) {
        try {
            Product product = new Product();
            if (imageFiles != null && !imageFiles.isEmpty()) {
                List<String> uniqueFileNames = imageUpload.uploadImages(imageFiles);
                product.setImageUrls(uniqueFileNames);
            } else {
                product.setImageUrls(null);  // Handle the case when no images are uploaded
            }
            product.setName(productDto.getName());
            product.setDescription(productDto.getDescription());
            product.setCategory(productDto.getCategory());
            product.setCostPrice(productDto.getCostPrice());
            product.setCurrentQuantity(productDto.getCurrentQuantity());
            product.setProductActivated(true);
            product.setProductDeleted(false);
            return productRepository.save(product);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

**Imageupload method implementation:
**
@Component
public class ImageUpload {

    private final String UPLOAD_DIR= "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Brototype\\Week 11\\TrendyThreads- Code\\Ecomv2\\Admin\\src\\main\\resources\\static\\img\\image-product";
    public List<String> uploadImages(List<MultipartFile> imageFiles) throws IOException {
        File uploadDir = new File(UPLOAD_DIR);
        if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
            uploadDir.mkdirs();
        }
        List<String> uniqueFileNames = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            for (MultipartFile imageFile : imageFiles) {
                String originalFileName = imageFile.getOriginalFilename();
                String fileExtension = originalFileName.substring(originalFileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
                String uniqueFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + fileExtension;

                Path destinationPath = Path.of(UPLOAD_DIR, uniqueFileName);
                while (Files.exists(destinationPath)) {
                    uniqueFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + fileExtension;
                    destinationPath = Path.of(UPLOAD_DIR, uniqueFileName);
                }

                Files.copy(imageFile.getInputStream(), destinationPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                uniqueFileNames.add(uniqueFileName);
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.getMessage();
            }
            return uniqueFileNames;
        }
}

**code in Thymeleaf:
**
<td>
<img style="height: 40px; width: 40px;" th:src="${#strings.concat('/static/img/image-product/', product.imageUrls[0])}" />
</td>
```

Error showing while inspecting page:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

But I can see the images in imageProduct file in static folder and can see the imagenames in imageUrls in database. They are just not showing up while I retrieve them from db and showing in front end!! Any solutions please.
I was trying to show the details of a bunch of products alongside any of the multiple image I am uploading (mainly the first image). But images are not showing up in the locally hosted web page.